# How to change Parity's TCP and UDP port to run an Ethereum node?

Tags: parity, nodes, installation, port-numbers

As far as I am aware the ports `30303/TCP` and `30303/UDP`, `30301/UDP` have to be accessible from the internet in order to run an Ethereum node.

I am running Parity and am sitting behind a firewall which only opens a small set of ports for me.

Is it possible and if yes how to change the ports using Parity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the following [parity cli options](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity#cli-options)?

- --port PORT              Override the port on which the node should listen
- --jsonrpc-port PORT      Specify the port portion of the JSONRPC API server

Comment: set the port to 0 to get an automatically generated one, like with Mist